# Filtering datatable with dropdown select

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mysql, frontend

I am trying to filter datatable by select.
I can see the data in select but don't know how to filter it.
Here's my code.

Thanks

```
function getSearchList() {

    $.post('@(Url.Action("GetSearchList", "ESR"))')
        .success(function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.each(data, function () {
                    $('#Search_Id').append($('<option>', {
                        value: this.ID,
                        text: this.S_ID
                    }));
                });
            }
            $(window).unblock();
        })
}
```

and

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Search_Id').select2({
            placeholder: "Search",
            allowClear: true,
        });
    });
```

and

```
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <select class="select" id="Search_Id"></select>
        </div>
```

following are whole backend side of codes
following are whole backend side of codes
following are whole backend side of codes
following are whole backend side of codes
following are whole backend side of codes
following are whole backend side of codes

```
    public List<SearchId> GetSearchIdData()
    {
        string strSQL = string.Format(@"SELECT ID, S_ID FROM TBR");

        using (var conn = SqlUtility.GetDBConnection())
        {
            conn.Open();
            return conn.Query<SearchId>(strSQL).ToList();
        }
    }
```

and

```
    public ActionResult GetSearchIdList()
    {
        JsonResult result;

        List<SearchId> List = service.GetSearchIdList();

        result = Json(List);
        result.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
        return result;
    }
```

and

```
public class SearchId
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string S_ID{ get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    public List<SearchId> GetSearchIdList()
    {
        return repo.GetSearchIdData();
    }
```

Comment: Where/How does `GetSearchIdData` get called?

Comment: in the backend side.
I added it above.